# PWA service-worker can't update without refresh page or F5

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

Good afternoon, I have a PWA application with an active service-worker to update. It works correctly when I enter the PWA or do F5. But the problem is that one of the PWA screens is a dashboard, in which the client could be for days (therefore it will not do F5) and it should be updated without F5. I'm testing with a setInterval (), but it doesn't catch the update until an F5 is done.

The code runs (I see the console.log every 5sec), but it doesn't find the update until I do an F5

My app.component:

```
initializeApp() {
    setInterval(() => { 
      console.log("cheking updates")
      if (this.swUpdate.available) {
        this.swUpdate.available.subscribe(() => {
          if (confirm("a new version si available."))
            window.location.reload();
          });
      }
    }, 5000)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that's how it's supposed to happen. Look at it this way, the service worker (*and your app*) are running in the browser.

When you deploy an app update, that app update hits the hosting server, if your app doesn't talk to the hosting server, it won't know that there is an update available.

I've always seen the `SwUpdate` observable more like a 'cache bypass' kind of update, when you refresh, it picks up the update, and loads the new version independently of the data you have in cache.